# Entitry Framework Code First - > tph -> Foreign key from base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a code first project with some Base classes.

I then have another project that inherits from those classes, adding some more properties, and then generating the DB.

Lets say for example we have a *Customer* and an *Address*:

```
public class Customer
{
     [Key]
     public int ID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [MaxLength(100)]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
     [Key]
     public int ID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [MaxLength(100)]
     public string CityName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

You'll notice that the Address has a foreign key to Customer.
This all works fine, but what I want to do is Inherit from Customer (or use a partial class) to add another property.

I stall want the database to have an Address and Customer table, but the implementing project should be able to add:

```
public class Customer : BaseObjects.Customer
{
    [Required]
    public int PantSize { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that the Base Address returns a Customer in the BaseObjects namespace, not this extended customer class type. So when I say

```
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

It either complains of having 2 classes with the same simple name (customer), or if I make them partial classes and generate the DBSet in the base DBContext it doesnt include the new property.

How can I do this?

thanks,
James

Comment: To clarify, I want to be able to have a class library of base data objects that are common across multiple websites, and then each website to extend these objects with new properties, tables, etc for more specific usage according to that site.  I want to be able to generate a base DB, but also generate specifically extended implementations of the DB for custom projects that extend the code base.

Comment: try renaming Customer to CustomerExtened, or always refer to the type by full type name

Comment: Won't that just give me another table called CustomerExtended? And the Address will still point to the base Customer and not populate all the data into the extended fields? I am looking to have a single Customer table with extended properties that get populated when an address loads the customer object

Comment: I use baseObjects and Extensions. But they are all from with one assembly. It gets ugly when the names are the same and only namespace differs. Recall the Obect/mode/store model internally in EF.

Comment: so if I did it from within the same assembly, is it possible to extend the base customer, have another object return a base customer, but have it return all the extended properties fully loaded from the db?